# Sound stops in Windows 8.1

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, mute

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I could not find anything similar with a quick search at the forum. I have a strange sound problem. The audio may mute for apparent no reason while playing a video on YouTube or Media Player Classic. To fix it, I go to Computer Management, Services and I stop the Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder services. Then I restart these two services and audio resumes without any problem. Should it happen again later, I restart the services and I have sound. Does anyone has any idea what's going on? Maybe a process tries to use an audio service and screws up? Any help appreciated.

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
CPU: Intel Core i3-3220 3.3GHz s1155
VGA: NVidia Geforce GT 620
Audio: Creative SoundBlaster Audigy Value

I have installed latest audio drivers and DirectX 9.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

The suggestion above didn't work for me but what I found was the issue was MS Windows 8.1 and up turn off the USB ports after a certain amount of time.  So I went into powersaving and stopped this from happening - problem went away :)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question proposed.