# Sound in Windows 8.1 randomly turns off

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

I am encountering a weird behaviour of my Windows 8.1 notebook. Sound randomly turns off when I'm doing… well, basically anything. It doesn't happen after a set period of time. If any sounds are playing at the moment, they will keep playing, but other applications aren't able to play sounds at all (as if the current output device doesn't exist).

I thought it was a bug with specific sound drivers combined with W8->W8.1 upgrade, but clean installation and MS drivers clearly deny this. Now my sounds revert to notebook speakers if audio decides to die.

I have tried a few things to solve this problem, mainly:

- disabling exclusive control for applications (didn't work)
- disabling enhancements (didn't do a thing)
- un- and replugging the cable (works sometimes, Windows switches active devices and it works for a brief period of time)
- disabling and enabling current audio device (worked at first, then I got error messages that another application is using the device - even though exclusive control was turned off)
- restarting the Windows Audio service (works, but sound dies off again half the time)
- restarting Windows (works, sound dies off after some undiscovered action)

I don't use any weird voicecommunication programs (only Skype and TeamSpeak sometimes) nor I have anything associated with audio editing/production installed. The drivers are from MS, as stated above.

My notebook is MSI CX61 0NF-450CZ with Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

[This unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/820878/sound-stops-in-windows-8-1) is probably related to the same thing. Does, please, anyone know the solution to this problem? It's quite annoying to restart the service or whole system quite often…

Answer (score -1):

I think it may be caused by the Windows drivers, you can check if the drivers do, or you can update the drivers to newest.